# Read bytes from array to an array of Java Class

Tags: java, arrays

I have a configuration file for a DOS program that I am updating . . .

The configuration file is 17512 bytes.  The first 128 bytes are header information the remaining bytes are divided into 256 records of 64 bytes each.  Each record contains specific information for a device like name (8 bytes), description (18 bytes), unit number (1 byte), and so on.  I am reading the file into a large byte array and then want to pull out the individual device information so it can be edited in a new GUI interface.

I have created a class Device that contains a field for the device name.  I wanted to create an array of this class to contain all 256 devices, but when I try to read in the individual device names, all 256 device end up with the last device that was read.  I am not sure where I went wrong.

Here is the code for Main.java

```
public class Main extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    ReadConfigFile.importConfigFile();          // Read config file into byte array.

    Device[] device = new Device[256];    // Create array of 256 Devices.

    device[0].code = Device.setCode(0);
    System.out.println(new String(device[0].code));   // First device correct here.
    device[255].code = Device.setCode(255);
    System.out.println(new String(device[0].code));   // First device now same as last?
    System.out.println(new String(device[255].code));

    Group root = new Group();

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 200);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Config File Editor");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

}
```

Here is the code for the class Device.  I only have the first field so far.  When I can get it working correctly, I will add the rest.

```
public class Device {

public static byte[] code;              // 8 bytes. (1 - 8).

public Device() {
    code = new byte[8];                 // Constructor correct?
}


public static byte[] setCode(int devNumber) {
    int devCodeByteStart = (128 + (64 * devNumber));    // Skip first 128 bytes to get to first device.
    int devCodeByteStop = (devCodeByteStart + 8);       // Get 8 bytes for device code.
    byte[] code = new byte[8];                          // Gives Null Pointer Exception if removed.

    for(int byteCount = devCodeByteStart; byteCount < devCodeByteStop; byteCount++) {
        code[byteCount - devCodeByteStart] = configFileBytes[byteCount];
    }
    return code;
}

}
```

If there is a better way to accomplish the task, I am open to suggestions.

Comment: Do you know what `static` means/does?

Comment: @Amit haha... so simple... :)

Comment: All instances of Device share the same code array because you have it declared static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes ! In fact, the new Device[X] only init your arrays with a size of 256 elements (it allocate 256 Devices possibilities in memory) but it don't initialize 256 Devices nor put 256 Devices in your array. For create your device I can suggest you this. Don't uses an Array of Devices (if you can take another way).

1°) Can you change your importConfig to construct a ByteBuffer in place of a byte[] ? Why ?
Because a ByteBuffer have "an index" who advance after read x byte

like this

```
     ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(65535); // 65535 is for example, In your code ByteBuffer need to be return by ReadConfigFile.importConfigFile();


    List<Device> devices = new ArrayList<Device>();


    byte[] unused = new byte[128];
    bb.get(unused); // this will return the 128 first bytes. ByteBuffer
                    // position is 129
    while (bb.hasRemaining()) {  // Make a check to Verify that bb have at least 8 bytes, if not, last code can be corrupted  => if you need it
        byte[] code = new byte[8]; // 8 byte for 1 code
        bb.get(code); // now code in set with the 8 next bytes 129-136 ;
        Device device = new Device(code); // set Directly the code with the constructor
        devices.add(device);
    }
```

You can eventually do that : 
Your Model

```
   /**
     *
     *
     *
     */
    public class Device {

        /** */
        private final byte[] code; // code don't need to be static. Static is for field who need to be shared over class/packages like constant or global field. If code

        /**
         *
         * @param code
         */
        public Device (final byte[] newCode) {

         this.code = Arrays.copyOf(newCode, newCode.length) ; ASSIGN A COPY
        }

        /**
         *
         * @return
         */
        public byte[] getCode() {
            return Arrays.copyOf(code, code.length); // RETURN A COPY
        }

    }
```

Your Main

```
public class MainClass extends Application {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

     ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(65535); // 65535 is for example, In your code ByteBuffer need to be return by ReadConfigFile.importConfigFile();


        List<Device> devices = UtilClass.createDevices();

        System.out.println(new String(device[0].getCode())); // First device
                                                             // correct
        // here.

        System.out.println(new String(device[0].getCode())); // First device now same
                                                        // as last?
        System.out.println(new String(device[255].getCode()));

        Group root = new Group();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 200);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Config File Editor");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

and the UtilClass

```
    public class UtilClass {

    public static List<Device> createDevices(){

   List<Device> result =  new ArrayList<Device>();


    byte[] unused = new byte[128];
    bb.get(unused); // this will return the 128 first bytes. ByteBuffer
                    // position is 129
    while (bb.hasRemaining()) {
        byte[] code = new byte[8]; // 8 byte for 1 code
        bb.get(code); // now code in set with the 8 next bytes 129-136 ;
        Device device = new Device(code); // set Directly the code with the constructor
        devices.add(device);
    }
    return result;
   }
```

}

Comment: I will give it a try. Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

It's not correct to expose an Array values over the class. 
With your code, everyone can change the value of the array.

`public static byte[] code;`  will expose the  value of the array. it's dangerous

1°) You need to well-encapsuled your array

`private static byte[] code = new byte[8];` // init the array

create a getter to return a copy of your array

2°) Ok for the static key word if your application need to share the array, but you need to work only with a copy of the array.

so the return need to be `Arrays.copyOf(code, code.length);`

3°) if the array need to be immutable use private static final to be sure it will never change. So, init the arrays in the declaration. Don't need to init on the constructor

Comment: I have removed static from the setCode method but now I get a 'non-static cannot be referenced from a static context' error. I do not understand why I am getting the error if I create the array of devices prior to calling the setCode method.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Sorry, maybe my explanation was so bad.

"non-static cannot be referenced from a static context" mean you cannot call a static field with a non static method. if you have a non-static method you can call your static field by this way :

```
`Device.code`
```

but it's a bad idea.

So try this :

```
package test;

public class MainClass extends Application {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        ReadConfigFile.importConfigFile(); // Read config file into byte array.

        Device[] device = new Device[256]; // Create array of 256 Devices. 




// Edit
       device[0] = new Device() ; // you need a Device at index X.  If not device[X] =  null and null.myMethod()  throw NPE
//






        device[0].setCode(0);
        System.out.println(new String(device[0].getCode())); // First device
                                                             // correct
        // here.
        device[255].setCode(255);
        System.out.println(new String(device[0].getCode())); // First device now same
                                                        // as last?
        System.out.println(new String(device[255].getCode()));

        Group root = new Group();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 200);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Config File Editor");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

=> Don't call your Starter Class "Main" (Not good for coding rules set and maintenability)

```
package test;

import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 *
 *
 *
 */
public class Device {

    /** */
    private byte[] code; // code don't need to be static. Static is for field who need to be shared over class/packages like constant or global field

    /**
     *
     * @param devNumber
     */
    public void setCode(final int devNumber) {
        byte codeTmp[] = new byte[8] ;
        int devCodeByteStart = (128 + (64 * devNumber)); // Skip first 128 bytes
                                                         // to get to first
                                                         // device.
        int devCodeByteStop = (devCodeByteStart + 8); // Get 8 bytes for device
                                                      // code.

        for (int byteCount = devCodeByteStart; byteCount < devCodeByteStop; byteCount++) {
            codeTmp[byteCount - devCodeByteStart] = configFileBytes[byteCount]; // WORK WITH A TMP ARRAY
        }
     this. code = Arrays.copyOf(codeTmp, codeTmp.length) ; ASSIGN A COPY A THE TMP ARRAY
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     */
    public byte[] getCode() {
        return Arrays.copyOf(code, code.length); // RETURN A COPY
    }

}
```

Array is now well-encapsulated... You set value by the setter (`Device[i].setCode()`) and get the value by the getter (`Device[i].getCode()`), who return a copy of the array

So, each device has is "own" code array

Comment: I have copied your example code and I still get a null pointer exception error when it gets to the line "device[0].setCode(0);".  Very frustrating.

Comment: It's normal... you don't set any value a index 0. Create a a Device, put it a index 0 then you can use it to set your code Like : device[0] = new Device(); At this time is "as you want" !! You can eventualy pass the "devNumber" as parameters to set the code[]

Comment: Okay, I got that to work.  Still a little confused why I create the the device twice.  I thought that the line Device[] device = new Device[256] would create the empty devices, but then I have to create the individual devices and put them in the array?